# How to call javascript from google app script via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have uploaded the JavaScript code in the **google app script** and want to call these codes via src and
**I didn't know the way.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages), you can call it in `script src`, if you serve `JSONP` using `ContentService` from your webapp.